# Range.PasteSpecial causes Runtime Error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

Requirement:

We have a chart with a considerable cardinality in filters. User wants to single-click print all permutations.

My idea:

Iterate all, setting the filters and rendering the chart as image to a single sheet (unfortunately, I haven't found a way to do it w/o using clipboard).

Solution:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

Sub PrintButton_Click()
    Dim ps As Worksheet
    Dim gs As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Dim c As ChartObject
    Dim s As Shapes
    Dim n As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set gs = Sheets("Graph")
    Set ps = gs
    Set c = gs.ChartObjects("Chart")

    n = 0
    For Each loopRow In Sheets("Klassen").UsedRange.Rows
        ' there seems to be 1024 PageBreaks per Sheet limit
        If n Mod 1024 = 0 Then
            Set ps = Sheets.Add(After:=ps)
            ps.Name = "Print" + IIf(n / 1024 = 0, "", "_" + CStr(n / 1024))
            ps.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
            Set s = ps.Shapes
            Set r = ps.Cells(1, 1)
        End If

        If loopRow.Row <> 1 And loopRow.Cells(1).Value <> "" And loopRow.Cells(2).Value <> "" Then
            gs.Cells(1, 2).Value = loopRow.Cells(1).Value
            gs.Cells(2, 2).Value = loopRow.Cells(2).Value

            c.CopyPicture
            DoEvents

            'Sleep 1000
            'DoEvents

            'EnsureClipboard (xlClipboardFormatPICT)
            'dbg = Application.ClipboardFormats(1)

            r.PasteSpecial
            'ps.Paste Destination:=r

            Set r = ps.Cells(s(s.Count).BottomRightCell.Row + 1, 1)
            r.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual

            'gs.Cells(1, 1).Copy
            'EnsureClipboard (xlClipboardFormatText)
        End If

        n = n + 1
    Next

    gs.Cells(1, 2).Value = "(All)"
    gs.Cells(2, 2).Value = "(All)"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub EnsureClipboard(desiredFmt As XlClipboardFormat)
    Dim present As Boolean

    DoEvents
    present = False
    Do While Not present
        aFmts = Application.ClipboardFormats
        For Each fmt In aFmts
            If fmt = desiredFmt Then
                present = True
            End If
        Next
        If Not present Then
            DoEvents
            Sleep 100
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Problem:

After a variable amount of iterations, Excel throws "Run-time error '1004' PasteSpecial method of Range class failed".

Debug:

Both "r.PasteSpecial" and "ps.Paste Destination:=r" fails.

dbg variable contains xlClipboardFormatPICT, so it seems the data is there and inspecting the clipboard confirms it.

I was even desperate enough to wait a whole second between copying and pasting to eliminate the race condition - paste typically fails after pretty much the same number of successes.

I'm using Office 365 ProPlus. Funny thing is it used to work on v1705, it fails on v1803. Even funnier is that for some time after the upgrade it worked, so I'm not sure if it would still work on previous version...

Comment: What is r at debug time?

Comment: It's "Print!$A$xxx", where xxx is variable - so as expected (otherwise "r.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual" would fail, I guess)